# where to set default solr query parameters for all requests

Tags: solr, solrconfig

I am still new to `Solr`. I am trying to find a place where I can put default query parameters.

I know I can set default query parameters in places such as
`<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">`
,
`<requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">`
, and
`<requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">`.

But what I really want is to set default query parameters for all the above three (or more) sections.

Example default parameters:

`<str name="defType">edismax</str>
<str name="qf">
          id^2.5
          name^2
       </str>`

Where should I place the above lines in `solrconfig.xml'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest Solr, you would use [initParams](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/InitParams+in+SolrConfig) section for that. The examples shipped with Solr demonstrate it.

Comment: do you know how to do this using the new Solr API (version 6.0 or higher)?

Comment: [Config API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/config-api.html) allows you to manipulate *initParams*. Or you can use *useParams* and [Request Parameters API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/request-parameters-api.html). The difference is kind of push (override) vs. pull (declare the dependency).

Comment: Do you have an example working because I can't find a single example about that?

Comment: films example [demonstrates](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/6.6.3/solr/example/films/README.txt#L65) Request Parameters API.

Comment: I was checking the example of the film and it looks that only updating the facets in the config.